# ExecJs throwing error for rails_admin on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am going through a recurrent problem, while hitting for admin dashboard in the rails_admin it give me error:

**ExecJS::ProgramError in RailsAdmin::Main#dashboard**

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.7/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/ra.nested-form-hooks.coffee)
```

line #9 has the following code:

```
= javascript_include_tag "rails_admin/rails_admin.js"
```

Solution tried:

1. I have tried the node.js installation
2. Modify JScript section in runtimes.rb file.

Nothing worked for me. If anyone has solved it, please let me know.

Comment: Which browser did you tested this on ?

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533729/jquery-2-1-1-in-ie9-get-error-0x800a01b6-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-obj

Comment: Its latest version of Google Chrome.
Version 42.0.2311.152 m

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Sorry for incomplete details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. In your Gemfile, put

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then run

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

I've read 1.9.0 has issues on Windows, and have used this workaround in the past, but the issue resurfaced in a newer project with Rails Admin today, leading me to your post. Of course it works on Ubuntu and Mac OSX. [Here's another post where this worked for someone else.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609359/613674)